# BigCommerce Speed Optimization alert for "Reduce unused JavaScript"

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

How to "Reduce unused JavaScript" in BigCommerce. There are some external links in the list like facebook and google.

[image]

Here are some examples.

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/644953559017038?v=2.9.108&amp;r=stable" async=""></script>

<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=32b9206856b6b312aad8799243cb8254" async="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-0d59c/stencil/5e7921e0-f25d-013b-de3a-0e522e24c7d7/e/bb005010-f362-013b-8376-060bcaae9c49/dist/theme-bundle.main.js" async=""></script>
```

Comment: Did you click on the link that says "Learn how to reduce unused JavaScript" ? https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/lighthouse/performance/unused-javascript/

Comment: Yes I did, but nothing there for BigCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

I'd forget about this misleading set of warnings. The tool does not interact with the pages so has no idea if code is used or not. And it does not identify if any of the resources actually have any effect on the user's experience.

If you still want to remove these warnings, then remove your Facebook and Google tracking code, the widget, and anything using jquery. You can't really remove the bundle as that is core to making your site work.

Comment: Yeah, we can't remove the js but we can somehow delay the loading.

Comment: I don't think that would make any difference to the warnings, but it may slightly change the user experience. Don't delay anything required to render the page, like the bundle. And if you do delay the tracking code, expect a slight reduction in your tracking numbers.